# Python Flask not deleting correct post with the given post title from SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to delete a post from a SQLAlchemy database in flask by grabbing the post using the post's title.

However, it seems to be deleting the first row in the post table, instead of deleting the actual post that I intended to delete.

Here is the delete post route:

```
@post.route('/admin_delete_post/<post_title>', methods=['POST'])
def delete_post(post_title):
    from mysite import db
    from mysite.models import Post
    post = Post.query.filter_by(title=post_title).first()
    if post:
        db.session.delete(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post has been deleted successfuly!', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    else:
        abort(404)
```

here is the html code:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
       {% for post in posts %}
           {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            ..............
            ..............
         <!-- Button trigger modal -->
         <button style="display: inline; float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
           Delete this post
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Warning!</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Are you sure to delete this post?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                  <form style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;" action="{{ url_for('post.delete_post', post_title=post.title) }}" method="post">
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <a href="{{ url_for('post.edit_post', post_title=post.title) }}">
            <button style="display: inline; float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Edit this post
            </button>
          </a>

      </div>
   <!-- Blog Post End -->
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code form your mysite? To me it seems as if the action takes place there. So we need to see it in order to answer your question.

Comment: As a start, you can try to send a HTTP POST request to the endpoint and see what happens. You can use ```curl``` for that if you are on linux. Further, can you please print out the variable ```post_title```. I suspect that this is not a string but rather a dictinoary. Thank you!

Comment: As you can see in the delete_post route it doesn't have form apart from the one that's already been embeded in the above HTML code which is responsible for the deletion action ...

Comment: <form style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;" action="{{ url_for('post.delete_post', post_title=post.title) }}" method="post">
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                  </form>